# How to use dependencies of C++ libs in Visual Studio regarding the header path

Tags: c++, visual-studio

We have several C++ libs that are used in applications and so many dependencies occur.

---

Example problem:
Lets say we have an application **AppA** that uses **libB** and **libC**. **libC** uses **libD**.  Each lib is a static library project, all libs are grouped in a solution and the dependencies are given to Visual Studio, so all libraries and the application are linked together and build in correct order.

Now I had to add the header path of **libB**, **libC** and **libD** to **AppA** and the path of **libD** to **libC** as **AdditionalIncludePath**. I think it would be much better, if every library could *define* its one include path and to use the dependency mechanism to add these paths to the include path of depended projects.

Is there such a mechanism?

I tried to use property sheets, but this would mean, that the dependency has to be defined twice.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you may have a design issue if AppA uses only LibC, but has to know the header path of LibD even though it doesn't use it directly.  If LibC and LibD are to be used separately they should build as independent units, and LibC should shield its users from LibD dependencies.  
Of course, that can't work if LibC builds on some objects defined in LibD, but then AppA kindof is using LibD directly.

An actual answer to your question:
If all your libraries are tied together in one solution, they probably share a single base path.  I.e. LibB is in Libraries/LibB, LibC is in Libraries/LibC.  If you add the base path to your application, and then make sure that every include that's NOT from the current project / folder uses a qualified path, then you don't have to add so many paths to your solution build.
For example, in LibC you would have:

```
// LibC File
#include "AFileFromLibC.h"
#include "LibD/AFileFromLibD.h"

//LibC Code goes here.
```